# metadata of a redleaf camera is null

Tags: c, onvif

I can get video from video stream (id 0) of RedLeaf RLC-DF2013 camera, but I get no data on data stream (id 1). I expect that I get motion information in this stream, but I don't.
What can be wrong? What steps I should follow to make the camera send me motion information data?
Sorry if I'm newbie in onvif.

Comment: "*What steps I should follow*" <- knowing nothing about [tag:onvif], I *still* think adding some actual code to the question would be a good first step.

Comment: yeah, as i said before, i'm a real newbie in onvif. but there's an existing code and an existing camera. the code works with bosch, but doesn't work with redleaf. how to begin in onvif? i think the beginning api may be GetCompatibleMetadataConfigurations of MediaBindingProxy. but it returns an empty result. how can i know that how can i make this function returns proper data?

Comment: it seems that the motion data is received in video stream. what can be wrong? should i open data stream somehow so that ffmpeg gets data in its own stream? if so how?

Comment: i found that for the camera, data should be got from analytics instead of metadata. but i don't know how.